# fixing the parse error in php

Tags: php

how can i correct this error i am getting when i try to load my page,

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\index.php on line 46
```

the code on line 46 is this one below

```
?>
```

and my code is this one

```
<?php session_start();?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<?php
if (isset ($_post['submit'])){
    $error_count = 0;
    $error_message = array();
//trim removes the spaces
  $validate = trim(strtolower($_post['validate']));
  if($validate != get_answer() ){ 
  $error_count++;
  $error_message['validate'] = "validation error";
   }  
 echo $error_count;
if( $error_count > 0){
?>
<form method="post">
<h1> <?php create_function()?></h1>
<label for="validation">Validate:</label>
<input type="text" name="validate" id="validate" />
<?php if(isset($error_message['validate'])):?>
<span style="color: red"><?php echo $error_message['validate']?></span>
<?php endif;?>
<span style="color: green">Reenter Answer to Question</span>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="email">
</form>
<?php
}
else{
?>
<form method="post">
<h1> <?php create_function()?></h1>
<label for="validation">Validate:</label>
<input type="text" name="validate" id="validate" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="email">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

what exactly am i doing wrong? and how can i fix it?

Comment: There is a process called debugging ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing one closing parenthesis `}`  I guess it should there before last php closing tag `?>`

```
 <!DOCTYPE html > <html lang = "en" >
  <? php if (isset($_post['submit'])) {
    $error_count = 0;
    $error_message = a rray(); //trim removes the spaces $validate=t rim(strtolower($_post[
    'validate']));
    if ($validate != g et_answer()) {
        $error_count++;
        $error_message['validate'] = "validation error";
    }
    echo $error_count;
    if ($error_count > 0) { ?>
    <form method="post">

<h1> <?php create_function() ?></h1>

        <label for="validation">Validate:</label>
        <input type="text" name="validate" id="validate" />
        <?php if (isset($error_message['validate'])) : ?>
<span style="color: red"><?php echo $error_message['validate'] ?></span>

        <?php
    endif; ?>
<span style="color: green">Reenter Answer to Question</span>

            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="email">
    </form>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <form method="post">

<h1> <?php create_function() ?></h1>

        <label for="validation">Validate:</label>
        <input type="text" name="validate" id="validate" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="email">
    </form>
    <?php }
} //guess you are missing this 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error stating at the end of the file is most likely missing closing parenthesis `}` as Dan mentioned.
You can debug it using a tool from your IDE. As for me, I'm using Adobe Dreamweaver and use its **Balance Braces** tool. 
It highlights the entire block if you have the correct opening and closing parenthesis.
I hope you would have this tool in your IDE and you could debug it.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the answer im using just notepad++ thanks

Comment: In notepad++, you just need to place the cursor next to the opening parenthesis, it will highlight the parenthesis with red if you have the correct ones.